# How to retrive data for the first time

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain to me how I can do a gridview in PHP and how to fill it with data from the database?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://phpgrid.com

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders"); 

// change column titles
$dg->set_col_title("orderNumber", "Order No.");
$dg->set_col_title("orderDate", "Order Date");
$dg->set_col_title("shippedDate", "Shipped Date");
$dg->set_col_title("customerNumber", "Customer No.");

// hide a column
$dg -> set_col_hidden("requiredDate");

// change default caption
$dg -> set_caption("Orders List");

$dg -> display();
```

examples can be found on http://phpgrid.com/example/

it's easy to use and looks pretty.

for get data from database check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Excellent, I will try this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found inside of the code that was shared to me, a way to fill a table with data from the database and I could edit and I edited the code and add a column in the table.

Part of the code is the following:

```
 $sql= "SELECT a.id,a.apaterno,a.amaterno,a.nombres,a.fingreso,a.status,c.descripcion,b.nombre,a.fnacimiento  FROM templeados a,tunidades b,tpuestos c where a.idunidad='".$un[0]."' and a.status='A' and a.idunidad=b.iniciales and a.puesto=c.clave order by a.idunidad,a.apaterno";
   $res=consulta($sql,$link);
   $cuan=cuantos($res);
   if($cuan==0){echo "<div class='error'>No hay empleados activos en la unidad ".$un[1]."!</div>";}else{
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function valida(){
      chec=document.getElementsByName("idemp");var res="Debes marcar el empleado";
      for(var i=0; i<chec.length; i++){if(chec[i].checked==true){res="ok";}}
      if(res=='ok'){
        return true;
      }else{alert(res); return false;}
     }
     </script>
<?php
    echo '<div class="inst">Selecciona al empleado del que deseas ver su historia:</div>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="historial.php" onsubmit="return valida();">';
    echo "<table><caption>Empleados Activos Registrados en la Unidad ".$un[1]."</caption><thead><tr><thead><th scope='col'>Select</th><th scope='col'>Id</th><th scope='col'>Apellido Paterno</th><th scope='col'>Apellido Materno</th><th scope='col'>Nombre(s)</th><th scope='col'>Fecha Ingreso</th><th scope='col'>Status</th><th scope='col'>Puesto</th><th scope='col'>Unidad</th><th scope='col'>Fnacimiento</th></tr></thead><tbody style='text-align:left;'>";
    $par=0;
    while($row=resul_arreglo($res)){
     echo "<tr";
     if($par==0){echo ">";$par=1;}else{echo " class='par'>";$par=0;}
     echo "<td><input type='radio' name='idemp' id='idemp' value='".$row[0]."'/></td><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".fecha_normal($row[4])."</td><td>";
    echo ($row[5]=="A")?"Activo":"Inactivo"; 
     echo "</td><td>".$row[6]."</td><td>".$row[7]."</td> <td>".$row[8]."</td>  </tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody><tfoot><tr><td>Select</td><td>Id</td><td>Apellido Patertno</td><td>Apellido Materno</td><td>Nombre(s)</td><td>Fecha Ingreso</td><td>Status</td><td>Puesto</td><td>Unidad</td><td>Unidad</td></tr></tfoot></table>";
    echo '<div class="centrado"><input type="submit" name="Ver" id="Ver" value="Ver Historial" class="boton" /></div></form><br />';
   }
   }else{echo '<div class="error">Error en los datos no se puede procesar</div>';}
  }else{
?>
```

Now I need to add a button to export to Excel.

I have no idea of how can do that.
In c# there is a class and is really easy to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.